# undefined method `new_password_path' with activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to use activeadmin and I'm getting this error message when I visit the url /admin

```
NoMethodError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new 

undefined method `new_password_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000712b248>:0x00000006c8f900>

<% end -%>
<%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' %>
<%= link_to t('active_admin.devise.links.forgot_your_password'), new_password_path(resource_name) %><br /> #this line is highlighted
<% end -%>
<%- if devise_mapping.confirmable? && controller_name != 'confirmations' %>

Trace of template inclusion: /var/www/htdocs/web99/.gem/bundler/gems/active_admin-1930da57a656/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
```

Note that this is not **my** code, but **theirs**, so I cannot modify it.
my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'mysql'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

My routes.rb :

```
Itdm::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably already restarted your server, but for anyone that is with the same problem, try restarting the server. Worked for me.

Activeadmin use devise for authentication and [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1358) is an issue in devise's [github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1358) that looks like with your problem.